# How can I make jenkins run "pip install"?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, pip

I have a git repo and would like to get jenkins to clone it then run

```
virtualenv venv --distribute
/bin/bash venv/source/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python tests.py
```

The console output from jenkins is:

```
+ virtualenv venv --distribute
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing distribute..........................done.
Installing pip...............done.
+ /bin/bash venv/bin/activate
+ pip install -r requirements.txt
Downloading/unpacking flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Running setup.py egg_info for package flask

SNIP

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/infatics-website/build/flask/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-hkdBAi-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/jenkins/.pip/pip.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've tried adding sudo before the command, but it's doesn't work either:

```
+ sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas how to get around this? Also when I run pip install -r requirement.txt in a terminal as the jenkins user it doesn't need sudo permission. Can I get jenkins (the process) to run as the jenkins user?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The fact that you have to run use `sudo` to run `pip` is a big warning that your virtual environment isn't working. The build output shows that `pip` is installing the requirements in your system site-packages directory, which is not the way virtualenv works.

Your build script doesn't actually preserve the activated virtual environment. The environment variables set by the activate script are set in a child bash process and are not propagated up to the build script. You should source the `activate` script instead of running a separate shell:

```
virtualenv venv --distribute
. venv/bin/activate 
pip install -r requirements.txt
python tests.py
```

If you're running this as one build step, that should work (and install your packages in *venv*). If you want to add more steps, you'll need to set the PATH environment variable in your other steps. You're probably better off providing full paths to `pip` and `python` to ensure you're not dependent on system package installations.

Comment: I recommend using a hidden directory for virtualenv, so that tests are not picked up inside the virtualenv:
```
virtualenv .pythonenv
source .pythonenv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python tests.py
```

Comment: How to install virtualenv itself?!

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
stage('test') {
     agent {
          docker {
               image 'qnib/pytest'
          }
     }
     steps {
          sh 'virtualenv venv && . venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt && python tests.py'
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree what has been said.... But to make this more "Jenkins"

Create a basic Project - and in the custom steps do something like this

```
PROJECT="Tree"


rm -Rf ~/Builds/$PROJECT
CODE_HOME=~/Builds/$PROJECT/code
PYENV_HOME=~/Builds/$PROJECT/python
export PYENV_HOME
export PYTHONPATH=""
echo "Creating new Python env"
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m venv  --clear $PYENV_HOME
source $PYENV_HOME/bin/activate

echo "Get Project"
mkdir -p $CODE_HOME
cd $CODE_HOME
git clone https://github.com/MyUsername/MyTree.git .

pip install --upgrade pip
pip install nose
pip install coverage
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

After this you can then do you nose tests etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make Jenkins execute pip install requirements on Windows machine:

In "Execute Windows batch command" pipeline

```
REM activate venv, update pip and install package
cmd /k "cd <path to your directory like C:\WebAPI> & .\venv\Scripts\activate.bat & python -m pip install -U pip & pip install -r .\requirements.txt"
```

`cmd /k` executes windows command prompt and you can add any commands there. `&` is a pipeline operator. So you can have multiple commands